# Status for the forms

Tags: status

When the status is set on the form as "Pending" does this mean that it will not go to the email for that form until Approved? Im new to this plugin.

Also When I submit the form it goes through but says URI invalid? 
Any suggestions on what this could be? Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about the Solspace Freeform module? Please update your question with more information.

Comment: As @AlexKendrick said, please clarify the add-on you're using here and update your question with more specific information.